# Getting null for async/await call in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, async-await, graphql, nestjs

Login function

```
async login(loginInput: LoginInput): Promise<Login | null> {
  if (!loginInput || !loginInput.email || !loginInput.password) return null;

  try {
    const user = await this.userService.validateUser({
      email: loginInput.email,
      password: loginInput.password,
    });
    var login: Login = new Login();
    login.accessToken = user.id; //test
    login.refreshToken = user.email; //test
    return login;
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Fetch functions

```
  async validateUser(
    input: ValidateUserInput,
  ): Promise<ValidateUserModel | null> {
    const query: string = `query validateUser { validateUser(email: "E1", password: "P1"), {id, email} }`; //test
    var user = await this.fetchData(this.url, query);
    return Promise.resolve(new ValidateUserModel(user.id, user.email));
  }

  async fetchData(url: string, query: string): Promise<any> {
    const res = fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query: query }),
    }).then((res) => res.json());
  }
```

Query

```
  @Query(() => Login, {nullable: true})
  async login(@Args('login') loginInput: LoginInput) {
    return await this.loginService.login(loginInput);
  }
```

Error

```
{
  "data": {
    "login": null
  }
}
```

I'm getting the null result even if the login data is correct and I belive that this is because of the async/await incorrect usage. But I do not know what I'm doing wrong :(

**Can you please help me to correct my code?**

Comment: Well, you could try inspecting if there is an error in `catch(err)` and `fetchData` doesn't return anything

Comment: Maybe return the res in your fetch Data function?

Answer (score 0):

I have improved my code like this.
Still not sure is this the best approach but it works

```
  async login(loginInput: LoginInput): Promise<Login | null> {
    if (!loginInput || !loginInput.email || !loginInput.password)
      throw new ForbiddenException();

    const user = await this.userService.validateUser({
      email: loginInput.email,
      password: loginInput.password,
    });

    if (!user) {
      throw new ForbiddenException();
    } else {
      var login: Login = new Login();
      login.accessToken = user.id; //test
      login.refreshToken = user.email; //test
      return login;
    }
  }


  async validateUser(input: ValidateUserInput): Promise<ValidateUserModel | null> {
    const query: string = `query validateUser { validateUser(email: "${input.email}", password: "${input.password}"), {id, email} }`; //test
    var user = await this.fetchData(this.url, query);
    if(user && user.validateUser) {
        const userData = user.validateUser;
        return new ValidateUserModel(userData.id, userData.email)
    }
    else return null;
  }

  async fetchData(url: string, query: string): Promise<any> {
    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query: query }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => res.data);
  }


  @Query(() => Login, {nullable: true})
  async login(@Args('login') loginInput: LoginInput) {
    return await this.loginService.login(loginInput);
  }
```

maybe someone will need it...